# Wordpress server folder/directory permissions

Tags: wordpress, permissions, server

Is there a a set of permissions that I can use for my directories/files secure enough that I do not have to change the permissions to add media or install plugins without using an FTP account(do not want to set this up). I currently have files on 644 and directories 755. Is there a combination of permissions that is secure enough to allow me to do so without making apache the owner and is secure?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

755 on directories and 644 on files is good.

Check this answers for more details : [Correct file permissions for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352747/4741913)

Comment: but i dont have ftp to update page and install plugins. is there another way to do so without setting up ftp ?

Comment: Hum... For uploading medias or add/update plugin on Wordpress admin, you don't need any FTP connection if the serveur have good configuration and if the FTP user used for uploading the Wordpress files is in appache group (48). It must not be root or in other group, if not, Wordpress (who use apache) can't acces to directory. 
If all this condition is good, 755 on directories and 644 on files is good.
However, if you can edit wp-config.php file, you can try to add `define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' )` [See more in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants)